# How can I generate a list of equations with loop in R?

Tags: r

everyone:
As a freshman,I want to generate a list of formulas in R,such as

```
eq1 <- S[,c(1)] ~ ylist + yinstlist + np[,c(1:1)]
eq2 <- S[,c(2)] ~ ylist + yinstlist + np[,c(1:2)]
.....
eq9 <- S[,c(9)] ~ ylist + yinstlist + np[,c(1:9)]
```

in stata,it can be

```
forvalues num=1(1)9 {
    global eq`num' "(s`num' $ylist $zlist np1-np$neq)"
    macro list eq`num'
    global eqlist "$eqlist \$eq`num'"
}
```

I have tried code as following:

```
eps <- list()
for (i in 1:8) {
  eq_single <- formula(paste0('S[,',i,'] ~ ylist + yinstlist + np[,',1:i,']'))
  eps[[i]] = eq_single
}
```

But this code did not work.It shows that:

```
1: Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1.
  Consider formula(paste(x, collapse = " ")) instead
```

I wonder if you can figure out my mistakes.
Many Thanks

Comment: Generate a list of characters and use as.formula to convert to formula.

Comment: sorry，I wonder if you can give me an example,I'm not very familiar with R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finished this question,the following is my solution:

```
eps <- list()
for (i in 1:8) {
  eq_single <- formula(paste0('S[,',i,'] ~ ylist + yinstlist + np[1:',8,']'))
  eps[[i]] = eq_single
}
```